# Connect Magento to Google Cloud SQL as MySQL Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I uploaded an already working database to Google Cloud SQL and I changed config.xml and local.xml. The connection data I filled in is working. I also tried the connection to the Google Cloud SQL database with a wordpress testversion. It has to be something else.

config.xml like:

```
<host>google cloud server ip</host>
                    <username>root</username>
                    <password>mypassword</password>
                    <dbname>magento</dbname>
                    <model>mysql4</model>
                    <initStatements>SET NAMES utf8</initStatements>
                    <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                    <active>0</active>
```

local.xml like:

```
<host><![CDATA[google cloud server ip]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[mypassword]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[magento<]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <active>1</active>
```

I get 2 different errors:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timeout
```

with this message:

```
#0 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/var/cache/ew/files/7a/3e/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(497): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/var/cache/ew/files/7a/3e/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(539): Mage_Core_Model_CacheOverriddenClass->_initOptions()
#13 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_CacheOverriddenClass->canUse('config')
#14 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /html/copy_hzlbio/var/www/vhosts/live_magento/htdocs/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Comment: When you say "The connection data I filled in is working." Where is it working from? The localhost on the Google Cloud? What is your GRANT statement for accessing the DB/Tables?

Comment: I tried to connect from wordpress and with heidisql. Both did work

Comment: I'm trying to discern if the failure to connect is related to the GRANT being specific to certain hosts. Are the WP and HeidiSQL both on the same server as the Magento install?

Comment: You are correct. There is a limitation of IP's that are able to connect. I added the server IP already. That should work.

Comment: But i will try it again with wordpress to know that it is not about the sql connection itself.

Comment: But there are two places where you would need to add it. One in the MySQL configuration and one in the GRANT statement for the user. Either one being off could cause issues. Did you apply a GRANT statement like `GRANT ALL ON magento.* TO 'root'@'magento_server_ip';`?

Comment: Where exactly do you mean to change that?

Comment: You can issue the statement in the `mysql` command line tool or whatever tool you use for managing your MySQL installations.

Answer (score 0):

It was not about magento or google cloud sql. It was about the server on which the htdocs are. The server does not allow this outgoing connection.